# Nesting and inheriting async/Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, cross-platform

I'm working on a PCL which has an `async` API (I'm new to the topic). From the research I've done online I'm confused about behavior and design implications. Say the application consumes some entry point API which wraps up some abstracted bottom layer to access files. Assume this code is running client side.

```
public interface IFileProcessor
{
    Task ProcessFile(string filename);
}

public class MyFileProcessor : IFileProcessor
{
    // Adapter can be SomeAdapter or SomeOtherAdapter
    private IMyAdapter _adapter;

    public Task ProcessFile(string filename)
    {
        File file = await _adapter.GetFileAsync(filename).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Some CPU bound operation
        DoSomeWorkOnFile(file);

        await _adapter.SaveAsync(file);
    }

    private void DoSomeWorkOnFile(File file)
    {
        // do some CPU heavy work here
    }
}

internal interface IMyAdapter
{
    Task<File> GetFileAsync(string filename);
    Task SaveAsync(File file);
}

// Some adapter for a client that has an async API and is mainly I/O bound
internal class SomeAdapter : IMyAdapter
{
    private SomeClient _client;

    public async Task<File> GetFileAsync(string filename)
    {
        // Fetch from server or something
        return await _client.SearchForFileAsync(filename).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync(File file)
    {
        // Push to server or something
        await _client.SaveFileAsync(file).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

But say I have another adapter that has no `async` API and its operations are blocking:

```
// Some adapter for a client that has no async API and is mainly I/O bound
internal class SomeOtherAdapter : IMyAdapter
{
    private SomeOtherClient _client;

    // Don't declare as async since it can't await?
    public Task<File> GetFileAsync(string filename)
    {
        // Read from disk or something
        File file = _client.GetFile(filename);
        return Task.FromResult(file);
    }

    public Task SaveAsync(File file)
    {
        // Write to disk or something
        _client.Save(file);
    }
}
```

- Does `SomeOtherAdapter` have any business implementing `IMyAdapter` despite the behavioral differences?
- Is there any benefit to having IMyAdapter return `Task` types? Presumably the application calls `await MyFileProcessor.DoSomeWorkAsync(...)`, so why let the adapters be `async`?
- These operations are mainly I/O bound, not CPU bound - should that impact my decision in how I would design these components?

I know it's hard to capture the core question in a simple example, so my apologies if the example I'm giving is too trivial to make my questions clear.

Bonus question: If `MyFileProcessor` doesn't need to do any CPU bound work, is there any benefit to using `async` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does SomeOtherAdapter have any business implementing IMyAdapter despite the behavioral differences?

Yes. When you deal with interfaces, a task-returning method indicates that it may *possibly* be asynchronous. If you have a real (i.e., non-test-stub) implementation that is synchronous, I would note in the documentation of the interface itself that the method call may actually be synchronous.

> Is there any benefit to having IMyAdapter return Task types? Presumably the application calls await MyFileProcessor.DoSomeWorkAsync(...), so why let the adapters be async?

Yes. Your first example is with an asynchronous, I/O-bound operation, so it makes total sense to make the interface task-returning (i.e., async-compatible).

> These operations are mainly I/O bound, not CPU bound - should that impact my decision in how I would design these components?

Yes. Any time you have an interface that is likely to be implemented asynchronously, it should have async-compatible signatures for those methods.

> If MyFileProcessor doesn't need to do any CPU bound work, is there any benefit to using async at all?

I don't understand this question; it seems to imply that async should be used for CPU-bound work. But that's the opposite of how async works; async is a natural fit for I/O-bound code, not CPU-bound code.

You may be interested in my [`async` OOP](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-0-introduction.html) blog series.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I've read around and found some conflicting information for whether `async` is best for CPU-bound or I/O-bound work which led to some confusion.